# Ctrl-Click on references in spring.xml

Tags: eclipse, spring

In eclipse I can navigate to classes using "Ctrl-Click" in my .spring.xml files. But I cannot navigate to definitions of other beans that are referenced using "refs" by Ctrl-Click on the reference.

Is that available? How can I configure it, which eclipse-plugins are needed?

I have: Spring 2.5, Eclipse Helios. Both prescribed by my company.

Answer (score 3):

To get support for Spring Config Files in Eclipse you can use the [Spring IDE plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/156), or STS.

Comment: Does it resolve spring references to other beans? e.g. in ref="SomeBeanId" ??

Comment: @Bastl: Yes it does. (If the are in the same file, If not you have to configure the Spring Bean Config Sets (In Spring Explorer)) --- I dont want to be impolite: but why don't you tryed it by your self!

Comment: Works for me in Juno (even classes in xml weren't working prior to plugin). Thanks.